# Custom event GA4 - Event parameter key is missing

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am pushing an event from the server using an httpPost request in C#.

I'm not sure what is missing, but I don't see the 'event' parameter key when I push the event.

The event count appears to be correct.

Here is my JSON.

```
{"client_id":"server","events":{"name":"API_call","params":{"items":[{"method":"GetLicenceDetails"}]}}}
```

Here is my c# code to push the data. It's work well, and the GA4_Endpoint is properly formatted.

```
// endpoint : "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={0}&api_secret={1}";
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
              var data = SerializationHelper.SerializeToJson(analyticContainer);
              //https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload_post_body
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
              var e = await httpClient.PostAsync(GA4_Endpoint, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
              return e;
            }
```

Why in GA4 when i click on the event there is no event parameter key ? It's not supposed to show

> method

That is my realtime show.

[image]
[image]
[image]
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your JSON

```
{
   "client_id":"server",
   "events":{
      "name":"API_call",
      "params":{
         "items":[
            {
               "method":"GetLicenceDetails"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the JSON copy from the GA4 Measurement Protocol Document
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#recommended_parameters_for_reports

```
{
"client_id": "x",
"events": [
  {
    "name": "offline_purchase",
    "params": {
      "engagement_time_msec": "100",
      "session_id": "123"
    }
  }
]
}
```

The quick thing I can see is you have a `item` array which contains the parameter you expected.
So maybe the right version from your JSON is

```
{
   "client_id":"server",
   "events":{
      "name":"API_call",
      "params":{
          "method":"GetLicenceDetails"
      }
   }
}
```

But just curious about why there is a `item` in your JSON. Is it copy from the JSON which using for ecommerce?

Comment: Thanks with postman it's seen to work. I think you put the light on it. The items come from another post stack overflow, it's my error. If I had read the documentation properly, I would have understood that the item was too much. Thank
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload_post_body

Comment: In case of a purchase, params could be an array right ?

Comment: Only `items` can accept array. And `items` are only allowed in some of the ecommerce events. So basically I would said GA4 is not support `array` type at this point.